# Scan pdf documents in C# .Net

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

I have a pdf document of scanned images. Now I need to run a OCR on it. I know how to OCR an image but I cannot understand how to run an OCR on pdf file of images. Also it need to be in C# as I am trying to make a desktop application in .Net.
It would be great if anyone can help.

P.S. I used Tesseract OCR to run an OCR on the images.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: then google **extract pdf images c#**

Comment: Isn't their any way that I can OCR a pdf file without splitting it into images?

Comment: (to ocr pdf) - (you can ocr images) = (extract pdf images)

Comment: The images are handwritten scanned documents. so you are saying that Is should extract all the images and then run an OCR?